# Work Visa Sponsorship in Indonesia

Tags: working-visas, indonesia

Currently I am on visa sponsorship under a company in Hong Kong, however due to coronavirus I am on the verge of being laid off. So I am currently staying in Indonesia and my family has a business here (They are not Indonesian citizens either). Is it possible I just ask my family business to sponsor me for a work visa and just stay in Indonesia?

From what I read in the Indonesian visa pages, if I need a work sponsorship I need like 5 years of work experience. I am a fresh graduate and do not have work experience I am confused on how this can work. There are some other minor requirements I am confused about but in general are there anyone in this form who has went through this kind of experience that can share?

Comment: What is your citizenship and your immigration status in Indonesia? What is your family’s immigration status there?

Comment: We are all South Korean, and they are under the KITAS work visa. However the business they own is partnered with a local (Indonesian) person.